# Crystal reports date format needed

Tags: crystal-reports, date-formatting

I have two date parameters. My query where condition is like this:

```
Where DATE_FORMAT(gf.created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= date_format({?TRANS_DATE}, '%Y-%m-%d')
and
DATE_FORMAT(gf.created_date, '%Y-%m-%d')  <= date_format({?TRANS_DATE1},'%Y-%m-%d')
```

When I run the report, after selecting any date I am getting `mm/dd/yyyy` but I need `dd/mm/yyyy`.

How can I change the format?

Comment: have you tried formatting the data field?

Comment: Hi In parameter window once i selected the date it is displaying mm/dd/yyyy format but i need to show dd/mm/yyyy in that window.

Answer (score 0):

I must ask what sort of prompt is it, text or calender?

Assuming it's calender,  you can make the the parameter a string and use an edit mask to format it how you want ("00/00/0000" or whatever). Then use the `Date()` function to convert the string to a date in your record selection formula.

-- It's also worth noting Crystal uses your current locale to determine date formats.

Answer (score 0):

2 problems in your question

---

1) date comparison in query:

```
Where DATE_FORMAT(gf.created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
>= date_format({?TRANS_DATE}, '%Y-%m-%d')...
```

Conversion to string and string comparison works but,
since date comparison exists, you should use it:

```
Where gf.created_date >= {?TRANS_DATE}
```

---

2) Data selection is different from data prompting (this is your real question).
When you drop a Date field in the report you can right-click and select "Date" tab (or "Format embedded field") to choose the format you want to show to users.